# I am experiencing Failed to create provisioning profile error on xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter, ios-simulator

I'm trying to create a project in Xcode, Version 11.6 and I'm getting this error:-

"Failed to create provisioning profile.
There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it."

i have checked in the top in the schemes menu it does not say generic device, i don't have a iphone i am using simulator for my project , should i need developer account to fix this issue ???
[I have included the photo of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnfyV.png). i changed my bundle identifier could it caused this this issue......i am using latest ios 13.7 for my simulator and my xcode is updated up to date Any help would be appreciated.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run and test your application on the simulator only, just check off the 'Automatically manage signing' and then build your project. You don't need to have a developer account and provisioning profiles set into your project, if you want to run it on the simulator only. It will still show alert of 'requires a provisioning profile', but it will not affect while running your project on simulators.